# Collsion in 2D, find angle and final momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose that the collision is completely inelastic. Disregard friction as the surface is smooth.

Suppose that one is in the direction of $(1,0)$ and the other $(0,1)$. Is the final momentum the vector addition of both momentums? Final momentum is in the direction of $(1,1)$, then the angle is $\arctan(1/1)$? *(I used number 1 in case masses and velocities are equal to simplify the problem)*. Same procedure applies for different momentums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'm not sure you can call this "inelastic" collision as that implies that some kinetic energy is lost (due to heat from the collision for instance). If that's wrong feel free to correct me.

Start with writing out the conservation of momentum for the situation where two objects merge after colliding.

$$p_1+p_2=p_3$$
$$m_1v_1+m_2v_2=m_3v_3$$

You know that the mass has to be conserved:
$$m_3=m_1+m_2$$

And with that you can find the final velocity of $m_3$:

$$v_3=\frac{p_3}{m_3}$$
$$v_3=\frac{m_1v_1+m_2v_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

Assuming both masses are set to 1, it means your answer is correct regarding the angle (the velocity will not be 1,1 but it will be in that direction using that coordinate system). However you need to be careful how you define the angle - is the angle from the x axis or y axis, and in which direction (clock-wise / CCW)? etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clarify whether you are talking about an inelastic collision (a collision where kinetic energy is lost) and a completely inelastic collision (where the two masses physically join together and act as one object).

In all collisions, the vector sum of the momentums of all objects is conserved.

Suppose now that the mass moving along the x axis is $m_1$ and has a velocity $v_1 \hat{\imath}$ and the mass moving along the y axis is $m_2$ and has velocity $v_2 \hat{\jmath}$. If the collision between the two masses is perfectly inelastic (the masses join together), then the conservation of momentum says

$$ \vec{p}_1+\vec{p}_2 =\vec{p}_{\text{combined}} $$

Plugging in and solving for velocity, we find that the velocity of the newly joined object as

$$ \vec{v}_{\text{combined}} = \frac{1}{m_1+m_2} \Bigg( m_1 v_1 \hat{\imath} +m_2 v_2 \hat{\jmath}  \Bigg)$$

The magnitude and direction can be found by the [standard methods](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/magnitude-and-direction-of-vectors.html). Be careful with just plugging in $\arctan$ to find direction. $\arctan$ has a range of $[\pi/2,\pi/2]$ which means that it can give you results that are 180 degrees off.

Comment: Completely inelastic collision